# I am trying to import numpy for use in a Python script but I get the error "No module named numpy"

Tags: python, numpy

I am using MinGW on a 64-bit Windows machine. I am using Python 2.6.8. When I try to install numpy from http://sourceforge.net/projects/numpy/files/NumPy/ , the error comes up that it cannot find Python2.6 in the registry. Please walk me through what I should do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have `pip` installed?  That would generally be the best way to install it.

#### With `pip`

If you don't have `pip`, do the following:

1. Run `curl http://python-distribute.org/distribute_setup.py | python`. This provides you with tools you'll need to install the package manager.
2. Run `curl https://raw.github.com/pypa/pip/master/contrib/get-pip.py | python`. This installs the package manager.

Then run `pip install numpy`, and it should install for you.

#### If that doesn't work

Sometimes on Windows machines, installing more complex Python packages throws errors like `Unable to find vcvarsall.bat` or `gcc exited with status code 1` or something along those lines, which are compilation errors.  You can get around that by installing unofficial [pre-compiled binaries](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/), by running

```
easy_install http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/2kgjgnai/numpy-MKL-1.6.2.win-amd64-py2.6.exe
```

That installs a pre-compiled optimized binary of Numpy.  This isn't as perfect as installing it straight from the index, and sometimes there can be minor incompatibilities, but it should be fine for most purposes.

After this is completed, you should be able to `import numpy` without issue.

Comment: In trying your "With pip" option, I cannot do step 1 because I get the following: "error: can't create or remove files in install directory. [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Lib\\site-packages\\test-easy-install-27172.write-test' Lib\site-packages\ does not currently exist". It suggests changing the install directory via flag --install-dir, but curl does not have such an option (curl --help). Should I just create this directory, and if so, where? I cannot use your second option because I don't have easy_install (I think).

Comment: @user1748601 I didn't put the full set of instructions for getting `easy_install` and `pip` because it seemed out of the scope of the question, but try with [this method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-to-install-pip-on-windows/9038397#9038397) or [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-to-install-pip-on-windows), and once you get `pip` and `easy_install` installed (which you should have anyway) you should be good to go.

Comment: Thanks, I had several other problems, so I ended up just reinstalling Python and using an unofficial 64-bit version of numpy ("pip install numpy" didn't work b/c of 32/64-bit issues).